# Finding k where the absolute value correlation coefficient is 1

Tags: probability

So the question was that the distribution of random variable X and Y is that

$p(x) = \frac{1}{2}I\{x=-1\} + \frac{1}{2}I\{x=1\}$

$p(y) = \frac{1}{2}I\{y=-1\} + \frac{1}{2}I\{y=1\}$

And the joint density is given by

$p(x=1,y=1) = k$

[1] Now that new information is given that X and Y are independent. What is the value k?

[2] Unlike [1], another new information is given that the absolute value of correlation coefficient between X and Y are 1. Now what is k?

For the first question, my attempt was that since that X and Y are independent I thought

$p(x=1,y=1) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} = k$

For [2], I know that $Cor(X,Y) = \frac{\sigma_{X,Y}}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}$ which here saying $|Cor(X,Y)| = 1$

First that I try to find

$E(X) = \frac{1}{2} (-1) + \frac{1}{2} (1) = 0$

$E(Y) = \frac{1}{2} (-1) + \frac{1}{2} (1) = 0$

$E(X^2) = \frac{1}{2} (-1^2) + \frac{1}{2} (1^2) = 1$

$E(Y^2) = \frac{1}{2} (-1^2) + \frac{1}{2} (1^2) = 1$

$Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = 1^2 - 0^2 = 1$

$Var(Y) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = 1^2 - 0^2 = 1$

$\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)} = \sigma_X\sigma_Y = 1$

$\sigma_{XY} = Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) = E(XY) - 0 = E(XY)$

Now that I got $|E(XY)| = 1$

I tried to solve what the $E(XY)$ which I thought is

$E(XY) = \sum_{x,y} xy p(X=x,Y=y) = (-1)(-1)p(x=-1,y=-1) + (1)(-1)p(x=1,y=-1) + (-1)(1)p(x=-1,y=1) + k$

But Now I don't know how to find $p(x=-1,x=-1),p(x=1,x=-1),p(x=-1,x=1)$ Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: I've deleted my answer due the lack of reply.